# Symfony form type with check if already exists (LocationType) (Tried EventListener, Transformer. ...)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

## My wish

I want a independent form type for my `Location` entity which I can add everywhere I want. When it's null then it should be null and not an empty `Location`.

## Current problem

My problem is either that when I submit `null` then the previous set location will be used or when I fixed this issue its that the location is duplicated and not unique.

## Base code

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Location::class,
        'by_reference' => false
    ]);
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('place_id', null, ['property_path' => 'placeId'])
        ->add('latitude')
        ->add('longitude')
        ->add('description')
    ;
    // [...] See below examples [...]
}
```

## My tries

### EventListener

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event)
    {
//      $event->setData($this->locationRepository->find(19));
//      $event->getForm()->setData($this->locationRepository->find(17));
//      /** @var Location $value */
        $value = $event->getData();
//      var_dump(1, $value, $event->getForm()->getData()->getId());
        $location = null;
        if ($value)
        {
            $location = $this->locationRepository->findOneBy(['latitude' => $value->getLatitude(), 'longitude' => $value->getLongitude()]);
//          var_dump('Location found', $location->getId());
            if(!$location)
            {
                var_dump('-------------------- NEW LOCATION ----------------------------');
                $location = new Location();
                $location->setLongitude($value->getLongitude());
                $location->setLatitude($value->getLatitude());
                $location->setDescription($value->getDescription());
                $location->setPlaceId($value->getPlaceId());
            }
//          $event->setData($location);
//          $event->getForm()->setData($location);
        }
        $event->setData($location);
//      var_dump($location->getId());
```

It's working perfect - but not when I want to set it to `null`, because then it's ignored and the past location will be used.

#### Example `{}`

```
{}
```

**OK** because the `location` was not submitted so it's ignored. `$clearMissing = false` -> `$form->submit($request->request->all(), false);`

#### Example `{"location": {"latitude": 12.0, "longitude": 99.0}}`

```
{"location": {
    "latitude": 12.0,
    "longitude": 99.0
}}
```

**OK** because its **creating** new entity when lat/log *isn't* found and it reuses the existing entity when lat/lng *is* found.

#### Example `{"location": null}`

```
{"location": {
    "latitude": 12.0,
    "longitude": 99.0
}}
```

**Wrong, here I expect that the location is null and not the parent one.**

### ModelTransformer

```
class UniqueLocationTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $locationRepository;

    public function __construct(LocationRepository $locationRepository)
    {
        $this->locationRepository = $locationRepository;
    }

    public function transform($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if ($value)
        {
            $location = $this->locationRepository->findOneBy(['latitude' => $value->getLatitude(), 'longitude' => $value->getLongitude()]);
            if($location)
            {
                return $location;
            }
            $location = new Location();
            $location->setLongitude($value->getLongitude());
            $location->setLatitude($value->getLatitude());
            $location->setDescription($value->getDescription());
            $location->setPlaceId($value->getPlaceId());
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

It's working fine, too but even the problem with *setting null*.

#### Example `{}`

```
{}
```

**OK** because the `location` was not submitted so it's ignored. `$clearMissing = false` -> `$form->submit($request->request->all(), false);`

#### Example `{"location": {"latitude": 12.0, "longitude": 99.0}}`

```
{"location": {
    "latitude": 12.0,
    "longitude": 99.0
}}
```

**OK** because its **creating** new entity when lat/log *isn't* found and it reuses the existing entity when lat/lng *is* found.

#### Example `{"location": null}`

```
{"location": {
    "latitude": 12.0,
    "longitude": 99.0
}}
```

**Wrong, here I expect that the location is null and not the parent one.**

### Doctrine `prePersist` listener

Here the problem is that it's not called for updates and it's not so good because its out of the type scope.

## Update 17.7. 18:03 (gmt+2)

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event)
    {
        $value = $event->getData();
        $location = null;
        if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists('latitude', $value))
        {
            $location = $this->locationRepository->findOneBy(['latitude' => $value['latitude'], 'longitude' => @$value['longitude'] || 0]);
            if(!$location)
            {
                $location = new Location();
                $location->setLongitude(array_key_exists('longitude', $value) ? $value['longitude'] : null);
                $location->setLatitude(array_key_exists('latitude', $value) ? $value['latitude'] : null);
                $location->setDescription(array_key_exists('description', $value) ? $value['description'] : null);
                $location->setPlaceId(array_key_exists('place_id', $value) ? $value['place_id'] : null);
            }
        }
        var_dump($location);
        $event->setData($location);
    });
```

I changed the event listener now so that its listening on `PRE_SUBMIT` and added option `required` which is set to `false`.

But then I'm getting an error when submitting something valid.

Request:

```
{"location": {"latitude": 13, "longitude": 14}}
```

Response:

```
{
  "location": [
    "This value is not valid."
  ]
}
```

:(

Comment: `prePersist` doesn't fire on update. There's [another listener](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) for that

Comment: have you tried setting `'required' => false` in the LocationType defaults (in `configureOptions`)? because otherwise I would expect to always get a Location or some subtle form validation error, which you possibly don't check for?

Comment: I did it @Jakumi and now I'm getting `This value is not valid` error when submitting a valid location. Whats the problem?

Comment: The funny thing is when I make a `var_dump($location->getId());` in the entity it says `int(24)`. But why the entity manager tries then to create this location when it's already load from the database!? Wtf >.<

Comment: the error message might very well be due to the following: `getData()` returns an array (deducing from your code), so `setData()` probably expects an array too? pre_submit is maybe a bit early?

Comment: I fixed it by using `'by_reference' => true,` and using `$event->setData(null); $event->getForm()->setData($location);`. Seems to be fully working as I expected :-) Thanks very much for your ideas.